# What's The Difference Between Keys, Fields And Values In Acumatica API?

Tags: acumatica

Can someone enlight me on how Keys, Fields and Values in the Acumatica web services differs from one another? In which circumstance should I use each of them when Exporting and Submitting?

Thanks,
G

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically it's inherited from business layer.
Values - it;s just a fields on the screen
Keys - keys fields on the screen ( you can use search by key fields)
Fields - virtual fields that you can create